# Invalid types 'long int[long int]' for array subscript

Tags: c

I'm currently writing a  binary/decimal converter, and am getting stuck on a few errors. I need some help fixing them.

error 1:

```
assignment 1.c:10:23: error: invalid types 'long int[long int]' for array subscript
 scanf("%ld",&num[i]);
```

error 2:

```
assignment 1.c:11:11: error: invalid types 'long int[int]' for array subscript
if(num[0]==0){
```

error 3:

```
assignment 1.c:20:11: error: invalid types 'long int[int]' for array subscript
if(num[0]==1){
```

I'm not sure what the problem is with them, I might be making an obvious mistake.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

  long int num,decimalNumber=0,j=1,remainder,i;
  int bord;


  printf("Enter any number any binary number: ");
  scanf("%ld",&num[i]); 
  if(num[0]==0){

    while(num!=0){
      remainder=num%10;
      decimalNumber=decimalNumber+remainder*j;
      j=j*2;
      num=num/10;
    }
  }
  if(num[0]==1){
    printf("Press '1' for binary\n Press '2' for deciaml");
  }

  printf("Equivalent decimal value: %ld",decimalNumber);

  return 0;
}
```

The program is not finished.

Comment: `num` is a `long` and not an array, so `num[0]` doesn’t make any sense. What are you trying to accomplish by checking `if (num[0] == 0)`?

Comment: completely missed that one! what im trying to do is check if the number inputted is binary or not,(example: if the first number was '0' then i would know its binary) would that be the correct way of checking it?

Comment: @Bronson you might want to read chars instead.

Comment: It might be better to let the user pick the mode every time, either by prompting for binary or decimal beforehand or using a command-line flag (`base-convert --from-binary`, for example). A more consistent user experience and also easier to implement in code =)

Answer (score 1):

Code is attempting to index a non-array.  [@Ryan O'Hara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38732506/invalid-types-long-intlong-int-for-array-subscript/38732778#comment64841147_38732506)

```
// bad
long int num,...,i;
....
if(num[0]==0){
```

Instead simple use `if(num==0){`  or for OP's code, suspect `if(num != 0){` is really wanted.